# how to expand matematic formulas in <output>

Tags: html

I have three fields in which one is earn amount and second one is tax deduction and third

one is amount payable.Now its displaying for me the value of tax which is deducted from

the earn amount, but i want to see the total number that the tax is deduct from it too in

a amount payable box.

example: if our earn money is 1600 then the Tax is 32, but i want to have to value of 1568

into my amount payable field too ?

```
Here is the code:

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (earnamount.valueAsNumber) * ((taxdeduction.valueAsNumber))"
 oninput="amount.value">
  <legend>Test Environment.... Tax Deduction</legend>

  <p><label for="earnamount">&nbsp;&nbsp;Earn Amount</label>
  <input type="number" id="earnamount" name="earnamount"></p>

  <p><label for="taxdeduction">&nbsp;Tax Deduction</label>
  <input type="number" id="taxdeduction" value="0.02" name="taxdeduction"></p>

  <p><label for="amountpayable">Amount Payable</label>
  <input type="number" id="amountpayable" name="amountpayable"></p>

  <p>Total Tax In: <strong>AFN: <output name="amount" for="earnamount taxdeduction">0</output></strong></p>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to expand matematic formulas in output HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648629/how-to-expand-matematic-formulas-in-output-html-element)